# Difference between (|) Bitwise OR vs (^) Bitwise XOR in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I'm really getting confused on the use of the `|` OR vs `^` XOR in **JavaScript**, illustrated in the simple example below;

```
(function sayHi(n){
if(n < 1)   //base case
    return;
console.log("Hi!!" | "Hello!!") ;
sayHi(n - 1);   //recurse
})(5);


(function sayHi(n){
if(n < 1)   //base case
    return;
console.log("Hi!!" ^ "Hello!!") ;
sayHi(n - 1);   //recurse
})(5);
```

---

```
(function sayHi(n){
if(n < 1)   //base case
    return;
console.log(2 | 6) ;
sayHi(n - 1);   //recurse
})(5);


(function sayHi(n){
if(n < 1)   //base case
    return;
console.log(2 ^ 6) ;
sayHi(n - 1);   //recurse
})(5);
```

I'm confused about when, how, why, where I should appropriate use `|` vs `^`.

Can someone please help me make sense the major difference between `OR` and `XOR` operations?

I was reading the documentation for JavaScript from [MDN web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) to better understand the concept of bitwise operations, but I am struggling to understand their significant difference.

I just want to make sure I continue to use these operations correctly henceforth.

Thanks a lot for the anticipated help!

Comment: Please why did you build your examples to test the operators on strings and not on numbers?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OR and XOR are different operators:

- OR:

  ```
  0 | 0 = 0
  0 | 1 = 1
  1 | 0 = 1
  1 | 1 = 1
  ```
- XOR

  ```
  0 ^ 0 = 0
  0 ^ 1 = 1
  1 ^ 0 = 1
  1 ^ 1 = 0
  ```

If you have two bits and combine these with OR, the result will be 1, if one of these bits or both are 1. If you combine them with XOR (Exclusive OR) then it will be 1 if only one of these bits are 1 (not if both).

Answer (score 2):

**|** is a bitwise or

So, if either bit is set in two operands, it will be set in the result

**^** is an exclusive or, so if one bit is set in one of the operands, it will be set in the result, otherwise, it will not be set.

```js
var x,y;

for (x = 0; x <= 1; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y <= 1; y++) {
 console.log('XOR '+ x + "^" + y + "=" + (x^y));
 console.log('OR '+ x + "|" + y + "=" + (x|y));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise operators are typically used for checking whether a bit is `set` in a binary or not. You can vision it as a set of boolean values been compact it as a string `11100101`, where each `bit` is used to represent the `boolean` flag `true` or `false`, 1 for `set` and 0 for `unset` respectively.

Binary reading is done abit different from our usual English. It is done from right to left, with the most left bit been the most significant bit because it holds the greatest value and the left hand side bit been the least.

**Example:**

Value: 64 = binary `10000000`

Value:  1 = binary `00000001`

Now back to your question.

**Q:** I'm confused about when, how, why, where I should appropriate use | vs ^.

**A:**
Bitmask and its operators are more commonly seen in low level programming where `memory` is a constraint (small computing device) or on `performance` critical application.

Sounds advantageous to use right? But they have their downside as well and it is code `readability`. Memory is cheap and processing power is much more greater than what it used to be, so people tend to forgo this bit of advantage when doing high level application programming.

**Q:** Can someone please help me make sense the major difference between OR and XOR operations?

`OR` and `XOR` operations are used for comparing two binaries. Let say binary A and binary B.

In layman term. The `OR` operations `|` can be read as if the bit in A `OR` B is set then return as `set`, which is `1`.

**Example:**

```
10000000 // Value 64 in binary
00000001 // Value  1 in binary
10000001 // Gives you 65 when you perform | OR operation

= 65
```

`XOR` operation works a bit like `OR` but it has another special ability that is when two bits are the `same` it returns you `0` instead.

**Example:**

```
10000001 // Value 65 in binary
10000000 // Value 64 in binary
00000001 // Gives you 1 when you perform ^ XOR operation

= 1
```

From memory, you generally only use the `AND &` operator to check whether a bit is set or not. So you might be more interested in it and also the `shift` operations.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense, bitwise operators (OR, XOR, AND) can only be used on numbers, not strings.

Each number is represent in memory by bits, each of which is 1 or 0 (true or false, on or off, etc). 1 and 0 are digits, just like 1, 2, 3, 4 are digits in our counting system. This counting system used by computers is called binary.

Bitwise operations basically perform the namesake operation (OR, XOR, or AND) on every single bit in the two operands.

Take 5 ^ 3 (5 XOR 3) for example:

5 is represented in binary as `00000101`

3 is represented in binary as `00000011`

For each operation, you have a left input, and a right input.
XOR stands for eXclusive OR, and returns 1 if the left OR the right input is 1, but not if they are both 1.
OR returns 1 if either of the inputs is 1, so if both are 1, then the output will also be 1.

A bitwise operation on a number performs this for every corresponding bit in each number, so 5 ^ 3 = `00000110`, which is 6.

**Note:** Binary numbers are written from right to left. Each digit corresponds to a power of 2, like how digits correspond to powers of 10 when counting. The leftmost digit represents the highest power of 2 (in this case, 2 to the 7th, which is 128).

- 0 ^ 0 = 0 for the first 5 bits
- 1 ^ 0 = 1 for the 6th bit
- 0 ^ 1 = 1 for the 7th bit
- 1 ^ 1 = 0 for the 8th bit

Meanwhile, 5 | 3 = `00000111`, which is 7.

- 0 | 0 = 0 for the first 5 bits
- 1 | 0 = 1 for the 6th bit
- 0 | 1 = 1 for the 7th bit
- 1 | 1 = 1 for the 8th bit

Answer (score 0):

They are different math (logical) operators, more related to math than JavaScript.

`OR` / `|`, or called "Inclusive OR", is similar to the English phrase "A and/or B", there are 3 possibilities: not A but B, not B but A, both A and B.

`XOR` / `^`, or called "Exclusive OR", is similar to the English phrase "either A or B", there are only 2 possibilities: not A but B, not B but A. You can see that "both A and B" is excluded, so called "exclusive".

Reference:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective